# how to create bootable usb for ubuntu 12.04.3?

Tags: 12.04, windows, live-usb

I googled a lot throughout..but unable to find a software for making bootable usb pendrive of ubuntu 12.04.3. All the programs available right now supports ubuntu 12.04.2 . What to do???

Answer (score 0):

You can use universal usb installer.
This is already discussed in ubuntu site.
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: i downloaded it but it did not supports 12.04.3 version ...

Comment: you can select the 12.04 itself. 12.04.3 comes under it. And if that doesnt work , there always an option for unlisted linux iso at the very end of the list. That will surely work.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had success with UNetbootin.

Here's a link to its homepage:
http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Comment: thanx curois...

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the your solution**

- [Download Pen Drive Linux's USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)
- Rename your your Ubuntu 12.04.3 image file to Ubuntu 12.04
- Following the steps given here [How to make bootable pen drive](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)
- That is your pen drive will work perfectly.

---

**If that still doesn't work then:**

- If you have any previous **Ubuntu CD/DVD** boot from that and chose `Try Ubuntu` ( or refer your any friends who have Ubuntu Installed)
- Use [Startup Disk Creator](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)(best S/W to make bootable pen drives for Ubuntu)
- That's all.